# What do I have to fill in in the field "URL" in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, ubuntu-server

I have set up influxdb on my Ubuntu Server and now I want to set a database up in Grafana. I access the server via ssh from my windows pc. What do I have to fill in at URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a default set up itll be the URL to the influxdb server on the default port (8086) .
see https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/influxdb/

So if the influxdb server is on  192.168.0.100 the URL will be `http://192.168.0.100:8086/`